# Downloading debian Neo4j version from Windows

Tags: linux, neo4j

I'm trying to download the [Debian Neo4j version](http://debian.neo4j.org/) from a `Window 7` machine.  I'm not managing to find the URL in order to download the package/file .  I have installed the [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/releases) software for some linux commands.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**Update**
I found this link  -  https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/ . Know I need to figure out what is the best file to download in order to install it on an Ubuntu Machine

Comment: You need this :- https://info.neo4j.com/download-thanks.html?edition=community&release=3.2.3&flavour=unix . Just download and extract the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options :

1. If you've got access to the package repository (from your Ubuntu machine), follow the information in https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/ to install it as a package. That's the best option which also provides start/stop scripts, a user that runs Neo4j (neo4j) and also allows for easier upgrades.
2. If you can not reach the internet from your Ubuntu machine (as could be deduced from the way you're trying to do it, the zip (or tar.gz for Linux) download is the way to go. You can find that at http://info.neo4j.com/download-thanks.html?edition=community&release=3.2.3&flavour=unix

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom